# how to linegraph using result from the previous page

Tags: flutter

Can i create line graph which is the data get from previous page. I have done a calculation on my previous page. I would like to create line graph using the result and times. I face the problem to adjust the coding below because the coding below show the data was fix.

```
     series: <LineSeries<SalesData, String>>[
          LineSeries<SalesData, String>(
            dataSource:  <SalesData>[
              SalesData('Jan', 35),
              SalesData('Feb', 28),
              SalesData('Mar', 34),
              SalesData('Apr', 32),
              SalesData('May', 40)
            ],
```